# What "signal intent " actually means for TypeScript's read-only properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading [chapter: object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) of the TypeScript Handbook. And it said:

> It’s important to manage expectations of what `readonly` implies. It’s
> useful to signal intent during development time for TypeScript on how
> an object should be used. TypeScript doesn’t factor in whether
> properties on two types are `readonly` when checking whether those
> types are compatible, so `readonly` properties can also change via
> aliasing.

By saying "It’s important to manage expectations of what readonly implies. It’s useful to signal intent during development time for TypeScript on how an object should be used", what does it actually mean? I can figure out this is about the advantage of using `readonly`, but I still don't quite understand that.

Comment: Is this really just an English language question? _"to signal intent"_ means to communicate your intentions to others, in this case tell readers of the code/types how you expect the object to be interacted with. The example after that paragraph illustrates exactly the sort of problem the text describes (an object with a read-write property is a valid object with a read-only property, and the consumers accessing that property through the read-only interface may share a reference with consumers that can write to the property).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I'm not a native English speaker so it is quite difficult for me to understand its meaning. I mean the way it explained is not so direct and easy to understand.

Comment: Sure, I'm just trying to understand whether you don't understand what those words actually mean, or how they apply to the topic under discussion. From what you've posted it's unclear, and I'm not sure the former is really on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `readonly` property is to *signal* to other developers your *intent* to make that property read-only. But there are easy workarounds to write to that property anyway.